# Firebase Push Notifications on iOS: FCM says token error: not registered but app gets no refreshed token

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

After app installation my app gets PNs and evrything works fine. But suddenly, the app did not get any PNs anymore.

A manual pushtests to the specific tokenID gets the following answer from Google's Firebase Server:

```
{"multicast_id":XXXXXXXXXXX,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

So it seems that the token ID is not registered anymore in Firebase.

But I still get with `InstanceID.instanceID().token()` the same old token and not a new one.

I have quite the same setup like in the [Messaging Example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift)  from quickstart-ios. I have also already updated to the newest Pod Versions:

```
Installing Firebase 4.0.2 (was 3.6.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 4.0.1 (was 3.4.2)
Installing FirebaseCore (4.0.2)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.0 (was 1.0.8)
Installing FirebaseMessaging 2.0.0 (was 1.2.0)
```

But still with the same result: FCM connection and registration is working, also the same result with and without swizzling...

Any ideas how I should further debug this issue?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Pim i also face same issue. please help me if you find any solution.

Comment: @YogendraPatel check out my answer below. It's almost two years since I've answered this question and haven't seen the issue pop up since. So I'm quite confident that it's a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution... Of course I have no way to test this more rigorously since my single device that had this issue doesn't anymore. :)

You'll just have to register for remote notifications again.
`UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()`

Before, I used to check notification authorization status and only registered for remote notifications when it was `.notDetermined`. Now I also register for remote notifications right away when the authorization status is `.authorized`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, is this really working for you? You're saying "might have found a solution"..